# How can I configure persistence.xml for SQL server

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa

How can I configure persistence.xml file to connect to my SQL Server. Some information is connected as: Host, DatabaseName, UserName, Password, Port, ...

Comment: Which application server are you using? Are you using spring? or pure JEE5 managed beans JEE6? do you want to use hibernate native or JPA? please give more information about your stack of technologies ;).

Comment: I'm develop web based-on JSF2, and web server is glasshfish and JEE6.

Comment: Please don't use `[jsf]` tag for questions which have absolutely nothing to do with JSF. Only if you have problems with a JSF view (the Facelets/XHTML file) or with linking it to a JSF managedbean and/or understanding the JSF lifecycle, then you've really a JSF problem. But configuring JPA has nothing to do with JSF. You'd have exactly the same problem when using any other MVC framework like SpringMVC/Struts/Wicket/etc. This is not the first time that I removed the `[jsf]` tag from a quesiton of you please pay attention to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up a connection pool to MySQL database using a configuration `.xml` file can be pretty troublesome to someone who has just started like you.

In my opinion, you should take a look at this [short guide](http://www.javaxt.com/Tutorials/Glassfish/How_to_set_up_a_Connection_Pool). You simply need to start Glassfish server, open the browser and surf to `http://yourdomain.com:4848` to access the Admin panel. After that, just follow the instruction in that article and to create the `JDBC Connection pool` and `JDBC Resource`. At this point, you only need to open the `persistence.xml` file with your IDE (NetBeans, etc.) and set the `Data Source` property with name of your `JDBC Resource` and you're done.

One thing to note is that you must download the latest [MySQL Connector/J](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and copy the file

```
mysql-connector-java-<version>-bin.jar
```

into the folder

```
<GlassFish-install-folder>\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext
```

Otherwise, you will run into the expcetion `Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource` if you try to ping the database after creating the `JDBC Connection pool`.

Comment: "SQL Server" is not the same as "MySQL".

Answer (score 0):

First of all donwload jdbc driver for sqlserver and put that in glassfish lib directory and boot that.
Using Glassfish admin console:

1. define a jdbc connection pool and specify Host, DatabaseName,
   UserName, Password, Port, ...
2. define a jdbc resource and select connection pool name that you have specified in step 1
3. then grab the name of jdbc resource and put it in your persistence.xml file : `<jta-data-source>YOUR-JDBC-RESOURCE-NAME</jta-data-source>`

and now you can connect to data base.

If you are using Netbeans, it has some nice wizards to produce connection pool and jdbc resource in glassfish.

Since you are using JEE6 this is another way using annotation:

```
    import javax.annotation.sql.DataSourceDefinition;

@DataSourceDefinition(name = "java:app/env/myDatasource",
        minPoolSize = 0,
        initialPoolSize = 0,
        className = "your.driver.class",
        serverName="localhost",
        user = "admin",
        password = "admin",
        databaseName = "test"
)

public class DbConfiguration {
}
```

For more info take a look at [here](http://www.tech-juice.org/2012/05/30/datasourcedefinition-postgresql-example-in-java-ee/).

Comment: I done these step which link you give. My class `@DataSourceDefinition(name = "myDatasource",
  minPoolSize = 0,
  initialPoolSize = 0,
  className = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource",
  serverName="localhost",
  user = "xoso",
  password = "xoso~123",
  databaseName = "XoSoDB"
)`. When i retrive data it show error `Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : myDatasource__pm com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : myDatasource__pm at ...`

Comment: did you put your datasource in persistence.xml `<jta-data-source>java:app/env/myDatasource</jta-data-source>`

Comment: And when you want to use `@PersistenceContext` specify unitName too. `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "YourUnitName")`

Comment: Here is my code `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "ConnectToDBManuallyPU")
    private EntityManager em;
    
    public dotMB() {
    }
    public List<Dot> retriveAllDot()
    {
        TypedQuery<Dot> query = em.createNamedQuery("Dot.findAll", Dot.class);
        return query.getResultList();
    }`. And persistence `<persistence-unit name="ConnectToDBManuallyPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>myDatasource</jta-data-source>
    <class>Dot</class>
  </persistence-unit>` I run it show top error.